# How to split an array into a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a dataset saved as an array, but i want to split each string in this

array into an array (split at ',').

---

```
array = ["data1_1,data1_2","data2_1,data2_2",.....,"data10_1,data10_2"]


print(split_this(array))
```

---

Console should output:

```
[["data1_1","data1_2"],["data2_1","data2_2"],.....,["data10_1","data10_2"]]
```

Comment: `print([i.split(",") for i in array])`?

Comment: yup, does work! +rep for you

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `map`:

```
list(map(lambda elem : elem.split(','), arr))
```